# Objective C ARC unable to free memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

According to the leaks tool, the following code results in a memory leak:

```
- (NSString *)emojiWithCode:(int)code {
    int sym = EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL(code);
    __block __weak NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&sym length:sizeof(sym) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
```

I tried to free the sym with free(&sym) but at that time the following error comes up:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x27d2e60c: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

How is this causing a leak if it is not allocated?
How can I free this memory correctly and solve the issue? 
EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL is this

```
#define EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL(x) ((((0x808080F0 | (x & 0x3F000) >> 4) | (x & 0xFC0) << 10) | (x & 0x1C0000) << 18) | (x & 0x3F) << 24);
```

I have attached the leaks tool screenshot as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using __block? And exactly what object is your memory being leaked on? sym, or the result string?

Comment: whats EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL

Comment: I bet the symbols are from a static array anyways

Comment: @BHendricks if you do not use __blocks with __weak it causes a warning(weak attribute cannot be used with automatic variables). That's why I am using it.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have edited my post EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL = #define EMOJI_CODE_TO_SYMBOL(x) ((((0x808080F0 | (x & 0x3F000) >> 4) | (x & 0xFC0) << 10) | (x & 0x1C0000) << 18) | (x & 0x3F) << 24);

Comment: @deltaaruna yes because allocing TO __weak is pointless > therefore the warning

Comment: the symbol is a stack var and can't leak. the macro is safe too

Comment: @Daij-Djan the reason why I added __weak to the result variable is the leaking indicated by leaks. So is this a false warning by leaks tool?

Comment: remove __block and __weak -- please post a screenshot of the leaks tool so we can see what leaks.... also: sure arc stuff can be picked up by the tool -- but it will go away later anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruments has no way of knowing why this object leaked, so it's only showing you the line of code where the leaked object was initially allocated. This line of code (once you remove the `__block` and `__weak`) is fine, so you have to dig in further to find out why this object leaked.

Bottom line, you don't have to do anything with this line of code, but rather you need to figure out where this string was subsequently used in order to identify why it leaked. Most likely, the object that used this string itself leaked (e.g. a strong reference cycle or something like a repeating timer that is holding on to the leaked object). And because that object leaked, this string also leaked. So, take your analysis up a level, and look where this string was used and figure out why it didn't get released.

I'd suggest you check out WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) for a tutorial on how to use Instruments to guide your research to identify the ultimate source of the leak.

Also, it's often worth doing a static analysis (choose "Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu), as in some situations it can identify sources of problems. Make sure the static analyzer gives you a clean bill of health before diving into Instruments. This is admittedly more useful in non-ARC code, but sometimes it can identify issues.